# Duplicated glyphs (except last one) in clipboard when copying ligatures with Fira Code font (lualatex)

Tags: fonts, luatex, minted, debugging

<strike>I tried to make Fira Code with minted copy-friendly, but it just doesn't work, and I don't know why. Other mono fonts like Ubuntu Mono and all regular non-mono fonts (that I have tried) are copying just fine. Other Fira Code fonts (Medium etc.) have the same problem.</strike>

I don't understand why I get duplicated glyphs (except last one) in ligatures when copying minted source code with Fira Code monofont (lualatex).

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{Fira Code}
\begin{document}
\begin{minted}{text}
if a === b {
  command
}
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

How it looks:

[image]

What comes out from clipboard (with font from `fonts-firacode` package):

```
i f
 a
 F F ===
 b
 {
c o m m a n d
}
```

Update:

I found out that `fonts-firacode` package (apt) is outdated, because result (text in clipboard) is now different:

```
if a ===== b {
command
}
```

For `=>` it is `>>=`, for `|>` - `||>`, for `<|` - `<<|`, therefore every glyph in ligatures except the last one is duplicated. It's definitely much more copy-friendly, but not quite.

Update:

The issue is related to any teletype text with Fira Code font (ligatures to be exact). Minted is just how I first discovered this problem.

Comment: I get five equal symbols: `if a ===== b {` but apart from this it looks ok. Compiled with a current lualatex and fira code 6.2 fonts.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, thanks. I did get this exact result with "FiraCode Nerd Font" font (somehow related to NERDTree extension for Neovim). I updated my font from GitHub (removed `fonts-firacode` package). Now it's the same with your result.

Comment: I suggest that you make a bug report for the font. You don't need minted, simply \ttfamily === shows the problem.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, I opened [an issue](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode/issues/1482) on GitHub. Thank you for the suggestion.